# Selenium raises BadStatusLine error

Tags: python, heroku, selenium-webdriver

Hi I'm using selenium in my web app on heroku. I used it to login to instagram but it raises a BadStatusLine error whenever selenium is sending keys to the user field/password field.

My code:

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
driver.get("http://www.instagram.com/")

#click login button to show login form
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # seconds
login_btn = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log in")
login_btn.click()

#enter username and password
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # seconds
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(login)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Try downloading the latest Chromedriver version

Comment: hmm I'm using heroku so how do I get the latest Chromedriver? My buildpacks currently consist of 1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver.git
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-xvfb-google-chrome.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who need, you will need

-[Two buildpacks](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver)

-Set stack to cedar-14

-Have chromedriver in your files. Point to it and set chromedriver options

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
chromedriver_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "chromedriver")
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chromedriver_path, chrome_options = options)
```